# Oracle UPDATE statment targets 4 columns but only 2 get updated. Why?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a PLSQL package, SQL_LOGGING_PKG, that contains an "execute_sql" public procedure that executes a SQL string that is passed to it using dynamic SQL. The intent is for the procedure to log the SQL before it is executed and then, after the SQL completes, update the log record with the number of records impacted and the execution end time.

I want the logging DML operations to be completely independent of the execution of the SQL. If there is any issue with logging, I just want to disregard the error. I also want the log operations to be committed to the database independent of the main transaction which is associated with the execution of the SQL passed. I want the caller of the procedure to control the committing of the SQL that they requested to be executed.

In my example below, I intentionally pass in an invalid SQL by referencing a column that doesn't exist.

When I examine the SQL_LOG file, I see that the original SQL_LOG record is inserted and then an update is performed to the record that was inserted. I know that the SQL_LOG record was updated because I see that the ROWS_AFFECTED was set to -1 and the LAST_UPD_TS was updated but the BACK_TRACE and ERROR_MESSAGE columns remain originally NULL values. I tried to hard code a literal in for these fields just to simplify the update, but the column values remain null.

All the code is below. I am open to other suggestions, especially if I am handling my transactions/commits incorrectly. I am a beginner.

```
CREATE TABLE SQL_LOG (
  SQL_LOG_ID NUMBER,
  SQL_TEXT CLOB,
  SESSION_ID VARCHAR2(256 BYTE),
  ROWS_AFFECTED NUMBER,
  ERROR_MESSAGE VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
  BACK_TRACE CLOB,
  CRET_OPER_ID VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  CRET_TS TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  UPDT_OPER_ID VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  LAST_UPDT_TS TIMESTAMP(6),
  PRIMARY KEY (SQL_LOG_ID) USING INDEX TABLESPACE FDS_DATA)
TABLESPACE FDS_DATA
STORAGE (
  INITIAL 64K
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED
)
LOGGING;
```

---

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SQL_LOGS_SEQ
  START WITH 81
  INCREMENT BY 1;
```

---

```
DECLARE
    l_P_SQL   CLOB;
BEGIN
    -- Variable initializations
    l_P_SQL := 'UPDATE COUNTRIES SET INVALIDCOL = COUNTRY_NAME';

    -- Call
    SQL_LOGGING_PKG.EXECUTE_SQL (P_SQL => l_P_SQL);

    COMMIT;
END;
```

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE SQL_LOGGING_PKG IS

    PROCEDURE execute_sql (p_sql IN CLOB);

END SQL_LOGGING_PKG;
/
```

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY SQL_LOGGING_PKG AS

    
    FUNCTION insert_log (
        p_sql_text IN CLOB
    ) RETURN INTEGER IS 
            
        PRAGMA autonomous_transaction;

        v_row_count      INTEGER;
        v_is_log_all_sql CHAR(1);
        v_sql_logs_seq   INTEGER;
        v_inserted_log   CHAR(1) := 'N';
    BEGIN
    
        v_sql_logs_seq := sql_logs_seq.nextval;

        INSERT INTO SQL_LOG (
            SQL_LOG_ID,
            SQL_TEXT,
            SESSION_ID,
            ROWS_AFFECTED,
            ERROR_MESSAGE,
            BACK_TRACE
        ) VALUES (
            v_sql_logs_seq,
            p_sql_text,
            SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SID'),
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL
        );
        
        COMMIT;

        RETURN v_sql_logs_seq;

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN            
            NULL; --Eat logging errors
    
    END;

    PROCEDURE update_log (
         p_sql_log_id IN INTEGER
        ,p_row_count  IN INTEGER
    ) IS 
            
        PRAGMA autonomous_transaction;

        v_row_count      INTEGER;
        v_is_log_all_sql CHAR(1);
        v_sql_logs_seq   INTEGER;
        v_inserted_log   CHAR(1) := 'N';
    BEGIN
                    
        UPDATE SQL_LOG L
        SET
            L.ROWS_AFFECTED = p_row_count,
            L.LAST_UPDT_TS  = current_timestamp
        WHERE
            L.SQL_LOG_ID    = p_sql_log_id;
            
        COMMIT;

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN            
            NULL; --Eat logging errors
    
    END;


    PROCEDURE log_error (
         p_sql_log_id   IN INTEGER
        ,error_message  IN VARCHAR2
        ,back_trace     IN CLOB
    ) IS 
            
        PRAGMA autonomous_transaction;

        v_row_count      INTEGER;
        v_is_log_all_sql CHAR(1);
        v_sql_logs_seq   INTEGER;
        v_inserted_log   CHAR(1) := 'N';
    BEGIN
                    
        UPDATE SQL_LOG L
            SET
                L.ROWS_AFFECTED = -1,
                L.ERROR_MESSAGE = error_message,
                L.BACK_TRACE    = back_trace,
                L.LAST_UPDT_TS  = current_timestamp
            WHERE
                L.SQL_LOG_ID    = p_sql_log_id;
         
        v_row_count := SQL%rowcount;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('log_error.v_row_count=' || v_row_count);
        COMMIT;

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN            
            NULL; --Eat logging errors
    
    END;

    PROCEDURE execute_sql (p_sql IN CLOB) IS    
        v_row_count      INTEGER;
        v_is_log_all_sql CHAR(1);
        v_sql_log_id     INTEGER;                
    BEGIN 
      
        v_is_log_all_sql := 'Y'; --For now

        IF v_is_log_all_sql = 'Y' THEN
            BEGIN            
                v_sql_log_id := insert_log(p_sql);    
       
            EXCEPTION
                WHEN OTHERS THEN
                    NULL; --Eat logging errors
    
            END;
    
        END IF;
    
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE p_sql;
        v_row_count := SQL%rowcount;  -- Get the number of rows affected
    
        IF v_is_log_all_sql = 'Y' THEN                
            update_log(v_sql_log_id, v_row_count);                            
        END IF;
    
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            --log_error(v_sql_log_id, dbms_utility.format_error_stack(), dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace());
            log_error(v_sql_log_id, 'stack', 'back');
            RAISE;            
    END;

END; --SQL_LOGGING_PKG;
/
```

Comment: 1. Do you need these DMLs to ever return anything (RETURNING)? Or just one-way DML with no return value(s)? 2. Is the reason for using a dynamic SQL procedure to accomplish the logging, or is there any other reason (e.g. inherit owner privileges)? 3. Do you need bind variables in these DMLs?

Answer (score 0):

I had to better differentiate the column name from the value being assigned.

Time to go to bed! Sorry.

But I am still open to other suggestions! I will consider all comments and be grateful for them.

PROCEDURE log_error (
p_sql_log_id     IN INTEGER
,p_error_message  IN VARCHAR2
,p_back_trace     IN CLOB
) IS

```
    PRAGMA autonomous_transaction;

    v_row_count      INTEGER;
    v_is_log_all_sql CHAR(1);
    v_sql_logs_seq   INTEGER;
    v_inserted_log   CHAR(1) := 'N';
BEGIN
                
    UPDATE SQL_LOG L
        SET
            L.ROWS_AFFECTED = -1,
            L.ERROR_MESSAGE = p_error_message,
            L.BACK_TRACE    = p_back_trace,
            L.LAST_UPDT_TS  = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        WHERE
            L.SQL_LOG_ID    = p_sql_log_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be cleaner and less error prone to insert at the end, rather than insert and then update.

Here's a version that works for me. I added a few additional fields you probably want. Of course you can take the same concept and break them out into separate named procedures with parameter lists if you prefer. This is simply the most compact way to demonstrate how to do it.

```
create table tab1(col1 integer,col2 integer); -- test table
/
CREATE TABLE SQL_LOG (
  SQL_LOG_ID NUMBER,
  SQL_TEXT CLOB,
  SESSION_ID VARCHAR2(256 BYTE),
  ROWS_AFFECTED NUMBER,
  error_number integer,
  error_message VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
  error_stack varchar2(4000 BYTE),
  error_backtrace varchar2(4000 BYTE),
  call_stack varchar2(4000 BYTE),
  execution_duration_interval interval day to second,
  CRET_OPER_ID VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  CRET_TS TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  UPDT_OPER_ID VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  LAST_UPDT_TS TIMESTAMP(6),
  PRIMARY KEY (SQL_LOG_ID) )
/  
create sequence s_sql_log_id
/
DECLARE
  PROCEDURE p_exec_dml (in_clob IN CLOB)
  AS
    var_start_time timestamp with time zone;
    var_end_time timestamp with time zone;
    var_error_number sql_log.error_number%TYPE;
    var_error_message sql_log.error_message%TYPE;
    var_error_stack sql_log.error_stack%TYPE;
    var_error_backtrace sql_log.error_backtrace%TYPE;
    var_call_stack sql_log.call_stack%TYPE;
    var_rows_affected sql_log.rows_affected%TYPE;
    var_execution_duration_interval sql_log.execution_duration_interval%TYPE;
    
    PROCEDURE pl_log 
    AS
      PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION; -- perform the logging insert in a separate transaction so we can commit it without impacting the original transaction
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO sql_log
             (sql_log_id,
              sql_text,
              session_id,
              rows_affected,
              error_number,
              error_message,
              error_stack,
              error_backtrace,
              call_stack,
              execution_duration_interval)
       VALUES (s_sql_log_id.NextVal,
               in_clob,
               SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SID'),
               var_rows_affected,
               var_error_number,
               var_error_message,
               var_error_stack,
               var_error_backtrace,
               var_call_stack,
               var_execution_duration_interval);
       COMMIT;
    END pl_log;    
  BEGIN
    BEGIN
      var_start_time := current_timestamp;
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE in_clob; -- execute the DML
      var_end_time := current_timestamp;
      var_execution_duration_interval := var_end_time - var_start_time;
      var_rows_affected := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
      pl_log; -- log success
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        var_end_time := current_timestamp;
        var_rows_affected := -1;
        var_execution_duration_interval := var_end_time - var_start_time;
        var_error_number := SQLCODE;
        var_error_message := SQLERRM;
        var_error_stack := dbms_utility.format_error_stack;
        var_error_backtrace := dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace;
        var_call_stack := dbms_utility.format_call_stack;
        pl_log; -- log failure
        RAISE; -- must cause the initiating call to fail
    END;
  END p_exec_dml;
BEGIN
  /* test random DML calls */
  p_exec_dml('insert into tab1 values (1,1)');
  p_exec_dml('insert into tab1 values (1,2)');
  p_exec_dml('update tab1 set col1 = 3 where col2 = 2');
  p_exec_dml('update tab1 set col5 = 3'); -- this one will fail
  COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    ROLLBACK; -- this will undo all the above work, but not the logging
    RAISE; 
END;
```

The main disadvantage to encapsulating SQL like this is the inability to handle RETURNING clauses, and the difficulty of handling bind variables. You *can* enhance this for bind variables, but the typing is tricky... you'd need to pass in a collection type of records with multiple datatype fields so it can support native types without casting everything to string, then transform that into a USING clause and execute the whole thing dynamically (execute immediate within an execute immediate). It will get ugly, but is doable.

I typically use this kind of logging mechanism for DDL, not for DML, so these complications don't arise for me.

Another thing to consider is whether you even need successful DMLs logged at all. If the errors are the main thing you're after, you would be more successful using a database-level system error trigger  (`CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER .. AFTER SERVERERROR ON DATABASE...`) which can log all the same kind of error info, including the SQL (in most cases), session identity, etc... then you don't restrict the flexibility of the DMLs... RETURNING and binds would be unhampered by the constraints of any centralized dynamic SQL.